# Insert statement and update statement bundle

Tags: stored-procedures, relational-database

In our system, some stored procedures bundle an insert statement and a update statement together. They execute an insert statement first. If there is a duplicated error for a unique field after the execution, they will execute a update statement. They are designed to use in a situation where it is unknown whether the data is in our DB or not.

The following is the structure of a such query

```
INSERT INTO table1
(...)
VALUES
  (...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  ...
```

In a situation, I need to update only one field of a table. I can use a such stored procedure, of course. I, however, am wondering whether I shall create a new update query just for updating data or not in terms of a good practice.

Any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're saying, then you are calling an update statement if the insert statement returns an error?

If so, then you could probably use an EXISTS to check if the field you are looking to update is in the DB before updating.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx

Comment: Thanks. But that isn't my question.